# Cache locality with Large structures in C

Tags: c, caching, struct

If I have a linked structure like this :

```
struct phonebook {
    char LastName[16];
    char FirstName[16];
    char Email[16];
    char PhoneNumber1[10];
    char PhoneNumber2[10];
    char Addr1[16];
    char Addr2[16];
    char City[10];
    char Country[12];
    char State[2];
    struct phonebook *pNext;
}
```

when I want to search someone match the last name,
I may use

```
while (pHead != NULL) {
    if (strcasecmp(lastname, pHead->LastName) == 0)
            return pHead;
    pHead = pHead->pNext;
}

return NULL;
```

something like this, but every time I get a phonebook node, the cache will load the whole structure and cache misses a lot.
So, how can I increase cache-hit rate?
How to get grouped `LastName`s in the cache?

Without hot/cold or break linked-list into chaining hash table.

Comment: See [this question re AoS versus SoA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323154/which-kind-of-data-organization-using-c-arrays-makes-fastest-code-and-why/5323220#5323220).

Comment: When you say 'the cache will load the whole structure and cache misses a lot', is that your surmise or result of actual profiling? It is quite unlikely (although not entirely impossible) that a phone book application would be as performance-sensitive as to noticeably suffer from cache misses.

Comment: When you're using an O(n) lookup algorithm, it doesn't make sense to worry about cache performance.  This is a difficult problem to approach because the 'right' answer from both a cache and operational complexity viewpoint is to use a hash table.

Comment: I use phone book just for example, what I want to know is that, except adjusting the structure as hot part or cold part, or changing the data structure (linked-list is what I want). How to improve the way to search?

Comment: @QuestionC: A hash table is unsorted, whereas the linked list may well be.

Comment: I know you don't want hot/cold solutions, but sticking the most recently found result on the front of the list would certainly help things.

Comment: @EricJ. If you keep a sorted list of your keys, then you have a sorted hash table.

Comment: @QuestionC You're right. But if we 'Must' search for a linked-list from head to tail, how can we do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, in the general case each node of your linked list could point to a completely different address range causing cache misses.

If your heap is unfragmented when you build your list, the overall memory space for the structure is likely to be contiguous, even if individual nodes are not (assuming you insert nodes into the middle of the chain with some frequency).  If your heap is fragmented at this point, the list will be spread much further.

If you are running into a fragmented heap but know approximately how large the linked list will be, you can pre-allocate a large block of memory when the program begins, and sub-allocate it as needed.  This potentially wastes RAM, but reduces the cache misses vs. the case that you allocated nodes against an already fragmented heap.

[TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) may also provide improvements to the cache hit rate, as it is fairly space-efficient for small allocations.  It also attempts to keep sequential small allocations in the same 4K memory page.

> How to improve the way to search

If your linked list is sorted, it is sorted only by one criteria.  You could maintain a separate data structure (e.g. a hash table) that maps a particular search key (e.g. LastName + FirstName) to the pointer for that node in your linked list.  This is conceptually similar to how a database has a clustered index representing the physical ordering of the rows and potentially multiple non-clustered indices for different search criteria (search by email, phone, name).

Comment: Pre-allocate makes them more dense in RAM. But I still need to load the other parts (etc. FirstName, Addr1, Addr2...) into cache. Miss rate is still high when I only need a small part of information in this structure.

Comment: As a minor improvement, you could look at how your struct is being packed.  Your arrays may well start on 32-bit or 64-bit boundaries using default settings.  Given your current field sizes, packing to byte or word boundaries would slightly reduce the size of each struct, slightly improving cache locality.

Answer (score 0):

> every time I get a phonebook node, the cache will load the whole structure and cache misses a lot.
>   So, how can I increase cache-hit rate?
>   How to get grouped LastNames in the cache?

C requires that the members of each struct object be laid out consecutively (but not necessarily contiguously) in memory.  Therefore, yes, the `LastName` arrays of the various structs are spread out in memory, even before you consider that the structs themselves may not be contiguous.  You cannot change that, as it is specified by C.

You could, however, create an index consisting of a dynamic array of smaller structures, such as

```
struct pb_index {
    char LastName[16];
    struct phonebook *entry;
}
```

The `LastName` arrays will be more dense within that dynamic array than within an array of `phonebook`s, so scanning through such an array will make more efficient use of the cache than would scanning through your linked list.

All the same, setting this up and maintaining it looks like a fair amount of work for probably very little gain.  If you have an efficiency problem then it would be better to use a data structure that affords more efficient access.  A hash table or a search tree might suit.

Comment: I think it's a kind of hot/cold method? What if i don't want to the structure? Is it possible to do that, make the last name array more dense.

Comment: @tonyyanxuan You can modify your `phonebook` structure, or you can use a different structure altogether (as in my answer), but you cannot use the existing structure unchanged to achieve a higher density of `LastName`s within the overall array or any part of the memory assigned to it.  As I said, C specifies that all members of one struct must be laid out in memory as a group, so between each pair of `LastName`s of adjacent `struct phonebook` objects will be all the other members of a `struct phonebook`, and maybe some padding as well.